# Node.js and Sphinx Connection and querying data?

Tags: node.js, sphinx, npm

Is it possible to connect sphinx server and query sphinx data with Node.js? if so, please suggest node modules that connect to sphinx server and query the sphinx data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it and can't vouch for it, but [limestone](https://github.com/kurokikaze/limestone/) is a Sphinx connector for node.js.

**Update:** Example:

```
var limestone = require("limestone").SphinxClient();

limestone.connect(9312, function(err) {
    if(err)
        return console.error(err);

    limestone.query({foo: "bar", maxmatches: 10}, function(err, answers) {
        if(err)
            console.error(err);
        else
            console.log(answers);
        limestone.disconnect();
    });
});
```